# How to properly write foreign exchange symbol in xaringan

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I am just wondering how to write foreign exchange symbol in xaringan, for example, **Japanese Yen, Euro**, etc. I just find that `\textyen` does not work for xaringan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`HTML Entities`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) (that is, `&#entity_number;`) to write currency symbols.

[Here](https://www.htmlsymbol.com/currency-symbols/) you can find a list of hex code to write the currency symbols.

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---

- The Yen sign looks like &#xA5;

- The Euro sign looks like &#x20AC;
```

---

[image: currency symbols in xaringaan]

---